# js variable accessible to other pages and how to do it?

Tags: javascript, cookies, query-string

If you want a certain variable to be avialable/ accessible / be share to multiple pages of your web app. I read that saving it in a cookie is the easiest way to do it. I've also seen some doing it using querystring.

But what is the best practice in doing such?

Comment: I feel comfirtable with `localStorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage

Comment: If you don't want to keep in mind to pass every value you want to share in the URL, use cookies. *edit:* of course local storage is even better if the environment you run the app in supports it.

Comment: Just don't use multiple pages :-) Nowadays it's quite easy.